# Create Replica using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, table, replication, schema-architecture

I am creating a Replica from an ArcSDE database using python/arcpy 
(CreateReplica_management (in_data, in_type, out_geodatabase, out_name, {access_type}, {initial_data_sender}, {expand_feature_classes_and_tables}, {reuse_schema}, {get_related_data}, {geometry_features}, archiving))

and the tables which are being replicated are empty, only the schema is replicated. Is it possible to replicate also all the data in the tables using arcpy?

Comment: What are you using for the geometry_features parameter, if anything?

Answer (score 1):

What you seems to be asking is how to copy a shp,feature class. The copy features in the management toolbox do that. THe arcpy documentation is pretty straightforward.

http://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy-features.htm

You could delete the unwanted fields with delete field if need be.

http://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/delete-field.htm

Precise your question if it's not what you seek.

Comment: I was not very clear maybe in my question, I am creating a Replica from a ArcSDE database

Comment: I see. Then I can be of no use. Good luck.